# How to run an executable file in Qt Installer Framework?

Tags: qt, installation, qt-installer, qtif

I have an executable file C:\CDM21226_Setup.exe which i want to run through Qt Installer Framework (QtIFW). Note that CDM21226_Setup.exe are the drivers not the application which i am going to install. I want to install the drivers through the installer first. I have tried following operation in component script but did not succeed.

- component.addElevatedOperation("Execute", "C:/CDM21226_Setup.exe");
- installer.execute("C:/CDM21226_Setup.exe");

If somebody knows how to run an exe file from Qt Installer Framework then please share here. I really need it but don't know how to do it.
I am using Qt 5.7 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the installer as an administrator then the `installer.execute()` will take effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `installer.performOperation("Execute", ["C:/CDM21226_Setup.exe"]);`